# How to set steps at Spring <task:scheduled>

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I want to use  with steps. By now I have only one task, but I want next steps configured in the XML and with different delay to start each one. Is that possible?

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="globalConsumerService" method="execute" fixed-delay="5000" initial-delay="30000" />
```

I know it is possible with spring-bath or quartz. But the first is only for test, not production, as saying at the doc. The second has too much configuration to track the before tasks, I do not need track the older tasks.

By now I am writing inside the java code, bu I would like to set it at the XML.

```
public class GlobalConsumerServiceImpl implements GlobalConsumerService {
public void execute() throws Exception {

        this.serviceResume.execute();

        this.serviceBackupConsumer.execute();

        this.serviceResume.execute();

        this.serviceOpenBlockConsumer.execute();

        this.serviceResume.execute();

        this.serviceRestoreConsumer.execute();

        this.serviceResume.execute();

        this.serviceCacheConsumer.execute();

        this.serviceResume.execute();

        this.serviceEmail.execute();

        this.serviceResume.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to run all the `execute()` methods one after the other. You want to make each `execute()` method dependent on the other. For example, `serviceResume.execute()` should run first, then `serviceBackupConsumer.execute()` and so on. And, there should not be any overlap between these methods. Is that right?

Comment: yes, thanks for the didactic. I also want to insert a delay between them.

Comment: I think you got me wrong for trying to elaborate my understanding. I was only trying to get more clarity on the issue to find the solution faster.